# Component works even with state mutation redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I know it can sound weird, but I would like to create an incoherent state in my Redux application as an example for students, and generate a bug.

So I made a state mutation on purpose but the component render correctly and everything is fine !

My example is just a simple counter app, you click on the button and the value displayed will be incremented.

My action :

```
export function incrementCounter() {
return {
    type: INCREMENT_COUNTER,
};
```

}

My reducer with state mutation :

```
export default function ressourceReducer(state = initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT_COUNTER:
    // here it is ( redux invariant even throw and error if activated )
        state.counter++; 
        return {
            counter: state.counter
        }

}
return state;
```

}

My component :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    counter: state.ressource.counter,
});
```

Root reducer :

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ressource: ressourceReducer
});
```

Problem,  the props this.props.counter is coherent, no rendering problem in the class...

Can you help to make a state mutation that will have a real impact ?

Comment: The state doesn't matter in your example, only what is being returned.  You won't be able to affect the output of this incoherently the way you want unless you make it modify external data (so it has side effects).  Or you could pass the `initialState` in as a `Immutable.Map()` and do something like `state.set('counter', state.get('counter') + 1);  return state` but that's not really redux related it's just immutable js

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

"make it modify external data" how so ? Do you have an idea of how I could transform this app to affect the outpout because of a state mutation ?

Comment: honestly the way to even get your code to a place where doing that would be feasible would be showing so many bad practices...im not even sure I could allow myself to violate the redux documentation that heretically

Comment: But the purpose is to make students aware of what kind of problem they could encountered doing a state mutation. That is why I need a real life exemple.

Comment: well, you could actually use your exact example and just move the `state.counter++` to right inside the return object like so: `return { counter: state.counter++ }` im not sure how valuable that will be though since it's mainly just a warning against bad javascript lol